# how can i send file data from android to python?

Tags: python, android

I want to send file of data from my android In other word { i want to Enter some data like name gender location age ....etc and this in android  then take this data and send it to python } can this be file sending ?? or it must be data ?!!

Comment: is you python code opening a server socket or are you writing web code using python?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Android Scripting](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/TableOfContents?tm=6) by using this you can create layer of scripting over Android.

Comment: Sorry but i need your help about scripting !!  how it can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

if it is an open sever socket then on the Android just use a client socket and send your data through. You'll have to decide what the format of the data is and how you will parse it but the commutation part is strait forward.

```
// Create a socket without a timeout
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("java.sun.com");
    int port = 80;

    // This constructor will block until the connection succeeds
    Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}

// Create a socket with a timeout
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("java.sun.com");
    int port = 80;
    SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);

    // Create an unbound socket
    Socket sock = new Socket();

    // This method will block no more than timeoutMs.
    // If the timeout occurs, SocketTimeoutException is thrown.
    int timeoutMs = 2000;   // 2 seconds
    sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: fine i open a socket @ my python side the server socket and its waiting for connection  and i add this (your code ) in the android but it  seems not connect !!! any suggestion

Comment: if i just simply want to create a socket    Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port); then i write a statement to be print to make sure the socket is connected but i didn't!! what to do ??